# asp.net core @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString in View does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, session-variables

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC 6 app.

In the controller, I am setting a session variable:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "First");
            return View();
        }
```

I access it from the View and can change the valie or remove the sessionID

```
@{
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "Second");
}
```

or

```
@{
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Remove("PrimaryNavigation");
}
```

In document.ready I call via Ajax to a controller

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
              $.ajax(
             {
                type:"POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("General", "Employer")',
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#dvBody").html(result);
                    },
             }
         );
        });
    </script>
```

In this controller-Method I ask for the session value and is shows the first value "First".

```
     public IActionResult General()
     {
        string aa=HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation"); 
        //aa has "First"           
        return View();
     }
```

In program.cs I have definied

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Why the session value is not keeped?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your controller method like

```
public IActionResult General()
{
   return Json(HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation"));
}
```

and use this in progam.cs before app.run()

```
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Thanks , I already have Usesession before app.run... And  return Json(HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation")); it is not needed.. When I ask again i the ctml for the value , still has the first value.